# AWS Pinpoint - Amplify - Android - Custom events are recorded in the console but it's not possible to filter by them

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have added AWS Pinpoint Analytics through Amplify in my Android application. I am recording custom events based on the [official tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/analytics/record/q/platform/android):

```
val event: AnalyticsEvent = AnalyticsEvent.builder()
        .name("PasswordReset")
        .addProperty("Channel", "SMS")
        .addProperty("Successful", true)
        .addProperty("ProcessDuration", 792)
        .addProperty("UserAge", 120.3)
        .build()

Amplify.Analytics.recordEvent(event)
```

The events are being recorded in the AWS Pinpoint console:

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not possible to filter by specific event (Session Start and Session End are the only possible filters):

[image]

How to show counts for each custom event I have created? How could I find properties values from each recorded event? If that is not possible then there is no point in creating custom events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case patience was the key. After about an hour the filter for the custom event appeared.[image]

Comment: Did you find a better way to  analyze the custom events？ 
For example, import the event record to database and query it with sql.

Comment: I didn't try any other way as it was basic use case, however as I can see you may e.g. [stream the events to kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/event-streams.html) and analyse them there.

Comment: @dragonfly have you looked into this further?

Comment: @alexrogo yes, I used Athena to create db and query with sql.